# How can I migrate my data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

How can I migrate my data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1?

I have converted my site from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate-data.html

Comment: Check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240255/magento1-to-magento2-data-migration

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UB Data Migration tool to migrate your data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1

Here is the link for reference:
https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Download the magento-2 migration tool from github.com via this link: https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/free-magento-2-data-migration-tool-improved/

Step 2: Paste the downloaded tool into the root directory of your Magento 2 website.

Step 3: Now run this folder on your browser. For example: if your website's name is "xyz.com" and the name of the downloaded Magento migration tool is "Magento Data Migration" then type like "www.xyz.com/magento_data_migration/"

Step 4: From here, your browser will show all the migration steps. Follow all of them to securely migrate your existing  Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1

NOTE: If you will be facing an error regarding the time zone, add the the below-mentioned code inside "index.php" in "magento_data_migration"
ini_set('date.timezone','Asia/Tehran');

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you:

1. Follow the migration document of Magento here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html
2. You need to find an reliable automated data migration tool to help you transfer data such as products, categories and orders from your old store on Magento 1 to Magento 2 smoothly, quickly and safely.