# Magento1 to Magento2 data migration

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, duplicate

I am new to Magento2, I need some guidance from magento geeks for migrating data from magento1 to magento2.

**Quick Overview**
I received a system that was built in magento2 from scratch. So I think there is no need to migrate the Themes, Extensions and other things except data from magento1 system as described in docs (see link below).

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate.html
```

I tried to read this link, and finally reached to this point where I have no understanding of settings.xml (see link below) file i:e which files I need to ignore, and which to include (That's the main issue)

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html#settings-migration-mode
```

Can someone please help me understand, what is the best way to migrate data/settings from Magento1 system to Magento2.

Feedback is much appreciated!!

Comment: please check my ans for step by step information about migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check following steps for DATA MIGRATION FROM MAGENTO 1 to MAGENTO 2

**Setup m1 database and setup m2 project**

Before start migration please install fresh magento, Also put magento1 database and Magento2 database on same server

**Stpe 1:**

```
Install datamigration tool in fresh Magento
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.5
```

**Step 2:**

```
Go to to this Directory "{your_root_directory}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4(Magento 1 version)/"
Rename file config.xml.dist to config.xml (remove .dist from end)
Rename file map.xml.dist to map.xml (remove .dist from end)
```

**Step 3:**

```
Open config.xml (From this directory "{your_root_directory}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4(Magento 1 version)/config.xml")
```

**Set database name, username and password on line number approx 100**

```
//Magento 1 database access
<source>
    <database host="localhost" name="mad1live" user="root" password="mysql123" />
</source>

//Magento 2 database access
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="mad2migration" user="root" password="mysql123" />
</destination>
```

---

```
Remove .dist from map.xml.dist on this line no approx 107 
Code after edit : <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4(Magento 1 version)/map.xml</map_file>
```

---

**Copy crypt key from magento 1 /app/etc/local.xml and set in config.xml
Example:**

```
<options>
    ...
    <crypt_key>f5c82fa911418341aec329db9f798f81</crypt_key>
    ...
</options>
```

---

**Step 4: Run folllwing commands one by one.**

```
sudo php bin/magento migrate:settings -r {{path_to_your_root_directory}}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml

sudo php bin/magento migrate:data -r {{path_to_your_root_directory}}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml

sudo php bin/magento migrate:delta -r {{path_to_your_root_directory}}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
```

sudo is also not necessary in commands.

Comment: Awesome guidline, its very helpful to me. Thanks @Aasim

Comment: Very nice explanation, @Aasim what if I don't want to do this as a fresh Install of Magento2. My Magento2 application is already complete. Do you think that I should copy all the theme/css/js changes after migrating data from M1-M2 as a fresh install of M2?

Comment: @IrfanAhmed I never tried that but I think that should work, please try and let me know if you get any error.

Comment: @AasimGoriya I follow your migration step but settings command run after     `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'principal' for key 'STORE_GROUP_CODE'`

Comment: @AasimGoriya,I migrated all data successfully, I need to skip orders, only need to migrate products and customers