# Magento 2.2.6 products not rendering on frontend after migration

Tags: magento2, products, migration

We migrated products from **Magento 1.9** to **Magento 2.2.6**.

**But Products are not rendering** on the **frontend** even after updating attributes on selecting all.

When we open **single product** in admin panel and **then save it**, it renders on frontend. But this is not a feasible solution since we have more than 5000 products.

Comment: did you try with reindexing command ? if not then please do reindexing first and also please check your log files as well and let me know if you get any error in your log file.

Comment: @AasimGoriya reindexing done, cache flush and cleaned , no error in log file.

Comment: please provide a solution. still not working.

Comment: please check my ans.

Comment: we are still looking for a solution .

Comment: please check my updated ans.

Comment: Any solution please..

Comment: Ohh! are you still facing an issue ?

Comment: can you try to disable all your thirdparty modules and check it again ?

Comment: we have installed fresh magento 2.3  and migrated categories and products to it. But still , in fresh also we are facing the issue. No products are rendering on frontend. But on saving each product separately from admin panel ,it comes on frontend.

Comment: Can you confirm you have perform all data migration steps ? please check my this ans for data migration and try it once again. I hope it will help you to figure it our your issue.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240255/magento1-to-magento2-data-migration/240276#240276

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: we checked the data migration steps , we did these right in fresh magento also but still we didn't find any solution.

Comment: some of products are rendering in fresh magento but they are very few in number. 
we have tried everything cache flushed, reindexing, product update attribute. But still the issue exist.

Comment: You can check this http://ec2-54-245-28-229.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/petitfresh/

Comment: Hi one more thing I want to tell you that is did you check your store ids ? is your magento 1 store ids same as magento 2 store ids ?

Comment: I've just remembered that I have got same issue after migration, store id issue

Comment: Hi I have checked the store id's , we have three stores english, french and german . 
ID's are same in both , magento 1 and 2 .

Comment: Also please check website ids and products attribute sat as well, if you forgot to check.

Comment: After running command php bin/magento migrate:data -r /{path}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.1/config.xml 
we are getting error of -  Integrity Check failed

Comment: During data migration command and delta command i got multiple warnings of Mismatch Entities and Volume Check failed in fresh magento .  
Please provide a solution.

Comment: You can ignore database entities, add the <ignore> tag to an entity in the map.xml file, like this:

<ignore>
   <field>sales_order_address_id</field>
</ignore>

Answer (score 0):

It might be re-indexing issue so try Magento reindex command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: reindexing is done, cache is flushed and cleaned but stilll not rendering on frontend. 
when I open a single product in admin and save it renders on frontend.