# Data migration from 1.9.2.4 to 2.3.1 - Failure

Tags: magento2.3, data-migration

Please Help me on this,
I have migrate data from magento 1.9.2.4 to 2.3.1 There is a error like this :-

> Notice: Undefined offset: 19 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\data-
>   migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\Eav\Data 279

Comment: Please Provide Full data about this, Error. ??

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 19 in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\Eav\Data
   279

Comment: Please follow all steps while migration, check my ans on here for all steps: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240255/magento1-to-magento2-data-migration/240276#240276

Comment: Thank you. I have followed the exact steps. Initially I got two errors (1) max_allowed_packet changed to 100M and (2) integrity constraint, hence used --auto option. Now above error occurred. It occurs when data migration has restarted. 2nd time onwards,